# How to filter navigation property of a list by LINQ and Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of `FirstLevelItem`s. Each item has a list of `SecondLevelItem`s.

```
public class FirstLevelItem {
    public List<SecondLevelItem> SecondLevelItems { get; set; }
}

public class SecondLevelItem{
    public bool Deleted {get; set;}
}
```

I want to return all `FirstLevelItem`s and filter `SecondLevelItem`s which are Deleted.

Comment: When you say, *"and filter"* do you mean you want to **only include** items which are deleted, or **exclude** items which are deleted?

Comment: Are we are talking about LINQ to objects or Entity Framework?

Comment: I mean only include items which are deleted.

Comment: What do you mean LINQ to objects or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you have a local collection and you want to filter the items that are not deleted from each element. In such case you can use this:

```
items.ForEach( item => 
   item.SecondLevelItems = item.SecondLevelItems.Where(s => !s.Deleted).ToList() );
```

Alternatively, if you are talking about a database, you could do:

```
var results = DataContext.FirstLevelItems.Select( fi => new { 
      FirstLevelItem = fi, 
      SecondLevelItems = fi.SecondLevelItems.Where( si => !si.Deleted ) 
} );
```

This will return tuples where `FirstLevelItem` property is the first level item itself, and `SecondLevelItems` property is the filtered list of second level items. However, make sure you access the `SecondLevelItems` property directly, not the `FirstLevelItem.SecondLevelItems` property, as that would lazily evaluate and query the database for all second level items.

It is interesting how everyone understood the problem differently :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Return all `FirstLevelItem`s that contain at least one `SecondLevelItem` that is deleted:

```
var result = DbContext.FirstLevelItems
    .Where(fl => fl.SecondLevelItems.Any(sl => sl.Deleted));
```

The [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Queryable_Any__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___) clause checks if a boolean condition is true for at least one item in a collection.

Comment: But this returns only FirstLevelItems witch have at least one SecondLevelItems. I want to return all FirstLevelItems

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have variable `list` of type `List<FirstLevelItem>`.

```
list = list.Select(listItem =>
{
    listItem.SecondLevelItems = listItem
        .SecondLevelItems
        .Where(secondLevelItem => secondLevelItem.Deleted)
        .ToList();
    return listItem;
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

this code maybe help you

```
 var fli = //get your FirstLevelItems
       var result= fli.SecondLevelItems.Where(x => x.Deleted);
```

Comment: This won't compile because `Where` returns type incompatible with `FirstLevelItem`.